# gitflow-maven-plugin permission denied error (jenkins-gitlab)

Tags: maven, jenkins, git-flow

We have a job (java) on our Jenkins server, that gets trigger by a webhook from our Gitlab server, but during the build the gitflow maven plugin complains on the permission denied? That usually means that there is a problem with the ssh keys...

I checked the following:

```
1.) jenkins can communicate with gitlab (the repo does get cloned)
2.) there is a user in gitlab that has developer rights and the project in question has a deploy key enabled (with write permissions)??
3.) The pom.xml file has the right scm connection.
```

The problem is that it should work :), I think the problem is with the gitflow-maven-plugin:

Stacktrace:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 39.587 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-30T13:06:17+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/197M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.10.0:release-finish (default-cli) on project template: release-finish: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Any advice would be helpful.

**Update**:

I found out the answer, if anybody else will have similar issuses, the quick solution is to use the "ssh agent" jenkins plugin that will persist the ssh key in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning this at the moment, I think it is because you don't have valid privilege to access this git repo, you might want to ask someone who can give you the access right but I'm not 100% sure if this is the case.

Comment: I don't think so, because I was able to clone the repo with that user...

Comment: @TomislavMikulin I saw your updates, you mean add a "sshagent"maven plugin in the pom file?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific...I'm new to Jenkins and I didn't find the configuration ...Many thanks

Comment: ..in jenkins you can install various plugins..and one of those plugins is the 
"ssh agent" plugin...after installing you just use it in your jenkins job...

Comment: It seems like I don't have the right to access this function, I can't find plugin manger on the Jenkins platform